# ' showing up as ? on Wordpress site live server only

Tags: php, database, wordpress

I have a wordpress site which I have set up on my localhost. I've just uploaded it to my hosting and imported the database but all the ' are displaying as � . I thought it might just be my posts as you can see from this example [here](http://theplaj.com/#post-26).

However if you look at the below image you can see that its even happening in the wordpress admin panel.

[image]

I thought it might be related to the way the database is set up but I have checked and they have all the exact same settings. I tried setting up a new database and importing the data to that and it didnt help.

Does anyone have any ideas would could be causing this as its the exact same as the localhost server? They both have utf8mb4_unicode_ci set up on all tables.

**SOLUTION:**

Cannot post this as an answer since this question was closed as a duplicate.  However, for anyone else who has this problem the below fixed it for me. It wasn't related to the database. The `wp-config.php` needed updating. I changed `define('DB_CHARSET', 'utf8mb4');` to `define('DB_CHARSET', 'utf8');`

Comment: For anyone who's having this same issue by changing the wp-config file from  define('DB_CHARSET', 'utf8mb4'); to define('DB_CHARSET', 'utf8'); it fixed the issue.

Comment: For the benefit of anyone else having the same problem, rather than putting the solution in the question, please post the solution below as an answer and the "accept" it.  Thanks.

Comment: Unable to put it as an answer as I would have done.If the duplicate is removed I will be able to answer it.

Comment: @Sparky I closed the question. If I should reopen, let me know and if this was a bad closed. However, the duplicate does seem to answer it. Yet, I did post this as a community wiki http://stackoverflow.com/a/35671835/1415724

Comment: @Fred-ii-, ok, I did not see it closed as duplicate until I refreshed the page.  Yes, the duplicate seems to cover it.

Comment: @Sparky I just noticed a vote to reopen. I don't know who did, but I don't think I should reopen at this point. If a moderator feels it should be, then I'll let them decide. I don't know where to throw myself here lol

Comment: @Fred-ii-, I voted to re-open *before* you posted your first comment.  I'm not allowed to retract my vote or I would.  The duplicate seems to cover this, so leave it closed.

Comment: @Sparky No worries. If a moderator sees it, we'll just *"leave well enough alone"* for now, and see what comes of it. *Cheers* and thanks for the additional edit to the OP's question. There's enough now to inform others who may be faced with the same or similar problem.

Answer (score 0):

These issues usually come from the database collation type. Change it to one that supports UTF-8. And make sure you select as UTF-8.

In mysql this is usually done with `SET NAMES utf8` or provide the options in PDO.

Since there is no code showing how this page is printed I cannot add in a solution.

Comment: the database collation is utf8mb4_unicode_ci which is the same as on the localhost server.

Comment: Fixed the issue it was a wp-config issue.